# JComboBox popup appears and hide immediately when clicking on its border (Bad User Experience)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, user-experience, visual-glitch

When you have a swing JComboBox and click on its border, the popup appears and disappears immediately. When I say click, I mean press the left button of the mouse and release immediately.

[image]

It may be considered a bad user experience because no user would expect it to happen. Any user would expect one of the following behaviors when clicking on a border of a combobox:

1. The popup to open and remain opened,
2. Or it not to open at all.

Surely no user would expect the popup to be opened and closed immediately.

The user does not click on the border on purpose. But it may happen frequently when the combobox is small and he tries to click on it quickly.

In the year 2000 somebody registered this behavior as a bug in openjdk site: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4346918

They've recognized it as a bug, but closed it with the resolution: "Won't fix", with the following observation:

> I've been able to reproduce the problem but it's not significant so
>   I'm not going to fix it. The problem is that the drop down portion of
>   the combo box will hide when the mouse is released after clicking on
>   the border. This bug doesn't have a very major impact.

I agree with them, that it doesn't have a very major impact. But I still think that it leads to a bad user experience and I would like to know if there is a simple workaround to make the popup either to remain opened or not to open at all when the user clicks on its border.

The described behavior can be reproduced by clicking the left mouse button on the border of any JComboBox. See below a simple code where it can be reproduced:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JComboBoxUX{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JComboBox<String> combobox = new JComboBox<String>(
                        new String[]{"aaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"});

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
                panel.add(combobox);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox UX");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setSize(300, 150);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't click on its border. Its only a pixel wide anyway. If it really bothers you when you will have to look at the details of the ComboBoxUI and create a custom LAF to handle the mouse click. Not worth it to me.

Comment: I don't click on the border on purpose. But it happens frequently, against my will, when I am not thinking about it and just want to use the combobox. It really bothers me, but I agree that it does not worth spending much time on it. I've just asked because, maybe, there was a simple solution to this glitch. I didn't find anything in the internet.

Comment: Note: User error != (JAVA BUG). For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok, maybe it cannot be considered a JAVA bug. I will remove the "JAVA BUG" and change it to "bad user experience". Also, I will explain it better and post a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Interesting issue.  I've verified the bug appears in several Look & Feel's: Metal, CDE/Motif, Nimbus, Windows, Windows Classic.  Switching LAF's (including to a custom LAF) will (likely) not solve the problem.

Comment: I would like to add the following: I've tried to reproduce that on a JavaFX combobox and there it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be in:

```
class BasicComboPopup extends ... {

    private Handler getHandler() {
        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler();
        }
        return handler;
    }

    private class Handler implements ... MouseListener ... {

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            //...
            Component source = (Component)e.getSource();
            Dimension size = source.getSize();
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle( 0, 0, size.width - 1, size.height - 1 );
            if ( !bounds.contains( e.getPoint() ) ) {
                //...
                comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By subtracting one from `size.width` and `size.height`, the mouse falls outside of the bounds of the arrow button, and the popup menu is hidden.

Fixing the issue is problematic.  The `Handler` class is `private`, so we can't extend it, the `getHandler()` is `private`, so we can't override that in `BasicComboPopup` either.

One could extend `MetalComboBoxUI` and override `createPopup()` to return a custom `ComboPopup`, such as one extending `BasicComboPopup` but extending `createMouseListener()` to return a similar class to the `Handler` above, but without the subtract ones.

Oh, and do the same thing for each LAF you wish to support.  Yuk.

Attacking the problem from the other direction, one could extend the `MetalComboBoxButton` (which is returned by `e.getSource()`) and override the `getSize()` method to return a dimension one pixel larger in both directions, when the menu is displayed.  Of course, you'd still need to extend and override the `MetalComboBoxUI` to create and install this custom button.

And again, you'd need to do the same thing for each LAF you wish to support.  Again, yuk.

Unfortunately, it does not appear that Swing has the needed hooks to easily override the needed functionalities, and has marked various classes as private internal implementation details, preventing their reuse (in order to prevent breakage later if they want to change the internals).

Comment: Perhaps if you attached this info to the bug report https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4346918, or filed a new bug with this information, then they would be willing to fix it.  My reading of the bug report is that they admit it is a bug, but not important enough to investigate.  But since you did investigate and can show the code that needs to be changed, they might change it.

Comment: @Enwired: I don't have an account with JDK Bug System (JBS).  You need OpenJDK Author status (or above) to create and edit bugs.  Both the original reporter and assignee are inactive, so I can't really even send them the analysis by e-mail.  I'll leave it to someone else who has that access level to add the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

AJNeufeld's suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you!

Below is the code, if someone needs it.

**JComboBoxGoodBorder.java:**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.ComboPopup;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI;

public class JComboBoxGoodBorder<T> extends JComboBox<T> {

    public JComboBoxGoodBorder(){
        super();
    }

    public JComboBoxGoodBorder(ComboBoxModel<T> aModel){
        super(aModel);
    }

    public JComboBoxGoodBorder(T[] items){
        super(items);
    }

    public JComboBoxGoodBorder(Vector<T> items){
        super(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI(){
        setUI(MetalComboBoxUIGoodBorder.createUI(this));
    }

    private static class MetalComboBoxUIGoodBorder extends MetalComboBoxUI {
        public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
            return new MetalComboBoxUIGoodBorder();         
        }

        @Override
        protected ComboPopup createPopup() {
            return new BasicComboPopup(comboBox) {
                @Override
                protected MouseListener createMouseListener(){
                    return new MouseAdapter(){
                        @Override
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (e.getSource() == list) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) || !comboBox.isEnabled())
                                return;

                            if ( comboBox.isEditable() ) {
                                Component comp = comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
                                if ((!(comp instanceof JComponent)) || ((JComponent)comp).isRequestFocusEnabled()) {
                                    comp.requestFocus();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (comboBox.isRequestFocusEnabled()) {
                                comboBox.requestFocus();
                            }
                            togglePopup();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (e.getSource() == list) {
                                if (list.getModel().getSize() > 0) {
                                    // JList mouse listener
                                    if (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() != list.getSelectedIndex()) {
                                        comboBox.setSelectedIndex( list.getSelectedIndex() );
                                    } else {
                                        comboBox.getEditor().setItem( list.getSelectedValue() );
                                    }
                                }
                                comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
                                // workaround for cancelling an edited item (bug 4530953)
                                if (comboBox.isEditable() && comboBox.getEditor() != null) {
                                    comboBox.configureEditor(comboBox.getEditor(),
                                            comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                            // JComboBox mouse listener
                            Component source = (Component)e.getSource();
                            Dimension size = source.getSize();
                            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle( 0, 0, size.width, size.height);
                            if ( !bounds.contains( e.getPoint() ) ) {
                                MouseEvent newEvent = convertMouseEvent( e );
                                Point location = newEvent.getPoint();
                                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                                list.computeVisibleRect( r );
                                if ( r.contains( location ) ) {
                                    if (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() != list.getSelectedIndex()) {
                                        comboBox.setSelectedIndex( list.getSelectedIndex() );
                                    } else {
                                        comboBox.getEditor().setItem( list.getSelectedValue() );
                                    }
                                }
                                comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
                            }
                            hasEntered = false;
                            stopAutoScrolling();
                        }
                    };
                }
            };         
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Test.java:**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JComboBoxGoodBorder<String> combobox = new JComboBoxGoodBorder<String>(
                        new String[]{"aaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"});

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
                panel.add(combobox);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Good Border");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to see that worked for you. "...and I would like to know if there is a simple workaround to make the popup either to remain opened or not to open at all when the user clicks on its border."  Sadly, it is not the simple workaround you requested.

Comment: Not so simple. But it works, it can be reused throughout my code (without extra work), and it was easy to do, with your help. Just needed to follow your instructions and copy/past the Handler inner class code.